# Deserializing a date with two possible formats with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am deserializing some JSON which contains date fields from a web service. Almost all of the time the date comes in like this:

```
2017-01-18T07:20:00Z
```

But on vary rare occasions that date comes in like this:

```
2017-01-18T07:20:42.9295582Z
```

The second time it seems to not pick up the Z at the end. I'm just going by the logs at the moment but was just wondering if anyone had any ideas.

Comment: That's a weird time resolution -- 100ns. Are you sure there are 7 digits after the decimal point?  If so that's probably why it's failing.

Comment: How are you converting the date currently? Do you've custom deserializers defined? Can you paste a sample code of how you're doing it?

Comment: It is a weird time resolution. I actually don't have much faith in the creator of the web service. I have managed to achieve what I want to achieve by avoiding the call that returns this funny date format.

For the record Bandi I was just letting Jackson handle it without creating a custom deserializer.